# android click event programmatically

Tags: android

Actually programmatically i want to click on some coordinates. i want to evoke a click event on that coordinates which i am providing programmatically.

Comment: be clear in your question dude

Comment: ok suppose i want to click on my screen at (6,3) ok so is it possible to click on that cordinate programatically .

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using [performClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29) if it's a specific view you want to click on.

Comment: no is there any method where i can provide a cordinate for click event so when that method is envoke it will click on that given cordinates.

Comment: Not that I know of. Do not think it exists.

Comment: **ya i am not able to find out can u suggest me anything how to achieve this**

Comment: No, as I said, I do not think it exists. Your only option is to use the method I specified above to perform clicks on views (buttons, images, layouts etc).

Answer (score 0):

As the question is not specific. I understand that u want to programmatically have click even in your app. So it is possible with Python if you need help and if i understood the question right let me know i will go into details. And one more thing in case if you want this information for using it in clicking app ads for example in Google AdMob Ads. i could say that it is the worst idea ever.)